# Digital Nomad Visa for Brazil (12 months)

Tags: visas, brazil, long-term, nomad

Has anyone successfully received the Digital Nomad Visa for Brazil?

How was the process?

I'm especially interested to know about whether translations of documents are required and if they should be notarized in the country where I would apply.

Also, can I apply via a consular office in a third country, like Argentina?

In my case I hold a US passport but it would be good to hear about experiences of other nationalities.

- [Official information in Portuguese here.](https://www.in.gov.br/web/dou/-/resolucao-cnig-mjsp-n-45-de-9-de-setembro-de-2021-375554693)
- [How to Apply for the Brazil Digital Nomad Visa](https://nomadsembassy.com/brazil-digital-nomad-visa/)

Comment: Could you share your citizenship and the countries you intend to apply from?

Comment: As this is about long term stays, this should be more appropriate on [expats.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

I just did some digging around Brazilian Foreign Affairs and Justice ministries websites and it seems there is no standard answer to both your questions since [*Every Brazilian Consulate has its own workflow. For any questions, please contact the Brazilian Consulate where your Visa Application will be processed*](https://(https://formulario-mre.serpro.gov.br/sci/pages/web/ui/#/instrucoes-iniciais-visto)).

I also could not find anything saying you should (or not) apply for Digital Nomad Visa in a 3rd country. It's only stated that there are different procedures if you apply from within Brazil or from outside it ([from your own link](https://www.in.gov.br/web/dou/-/resolucao-cnig-mjsp-n-45-de-9-de-setembro-de-2021-375554693)).

If you really intend to apply from Argentina, you should take a look at their [webpage (in spanish)](http://buenosaires.itamaraty.gov.br/es-es/Main.xml) and check which consular representation you should use, based on your current location in Argentina.

You could also check this [official social media accounts for consular services around the world (only in Portuguese, but it's just a map)](https://www.gov.br/mre/pt-br/centrais-de-conteudo/midias-sociais-representacoes) and contact the one you intend to use to obtain your Digital Nomad Visa.

Hope you succeed your visa application and have a nice time in Brazil!